# Logstash Docker image not being built for the right OS architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, logstash

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:8.6.1
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash"]
```

I built this image and push it to AWS ECR. When I spin up an ECS Task from this, I am getting the error:

```
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash.lib.sh: line 141: /usr/share/logstash/jdk/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash.lib.sh: line 141: /usr/share/logstash/jdk/bin/java: Success
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash: line 60: /usr/share/logstash/jdk/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash: line 60: /usr/share/logstash/jdk/bin/java: Success
```

My infrastructure is running Amazon EC2 instance based on their official AMI. I don't understand why I am getting this error as it was built on the same server, i.e. same OS architecture.

Any ideas?

Comment: I notice that the repository you are using also has separate `-arm64` and `-amd64` images: https://www.docker.elastic.co/r/logstash/logstash-oss You might try specifically using one of those (which ever one matches your server's architecture).

Comment: keep in mind there are official AMIs for amd64 and arm64.

Comment: @MarkB - I am getting the same error with that. I am on art64. Strange

Comment: @erik258 - I am usin the correct architecture AMI, x86_64

Comment: In one comment you said "arm64" in the next you said the AMI is x86_64. x86_64 would be AMD64 archtectiture, not ARM64. You should only use ARM64 docker images if your EC2 instance is a Graviton (ARM) instance.

Comment: @MarkB - wow sorry. That was a mistake (and I can't seem to edit it). I have run the docker build command on the same server where it will eventually be hosted. And I have also -amd64 image, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the ECS cluster has the configuration for a EFS volume which has the arm64 binaries built into them. As it's part of the "infra", it didn't need to be declared in the Dockerfile.

Easily missed and certainly not something anyone else could've helped with as none of that information was shared.

Hoping this helps someone one day.